# GestureDetector onSingleTapConfirmed and button click conflict

Tags: android, events, button, gesturedetector

My app has a layout with a button. The activity has a gesture detector that receives the onSingleTapConfirmed event, like this:

```
@Override public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) 
{ 
  mDetector.onTouchEvent(e); 
  return super.dispatchTouchEvent(e); 
}
```

where mDetector extends from GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.

But it also has a button said that overrides click event. The problem is that  when the button is pressed the onslingletapconfirmed event is also call afterwards. Is there a reasonable way to stop the propagation of the event and only the button click be activated?
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: just for understanding. you register a second event-listener on the same widget and then you just want one of the two listening? Despite of that, why not just setting the un-used listener = null?

Comment: I have and activity with this: `@Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        mDetector.onTouchEvent(e);

        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(e);
    }` where mDetector extends from GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener. Moreover, the activity layout has a button with a usual OnClickListener.

Comment: @ChathuraWijesinghe Sorry for answering so late. To solve this, I applied the same touch listener to the GestureOverlay that I had and some changes to the dispathTouchEvent method like: `@Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        boolean dispatched;
        Log.d(TAG, "dispatchTouchEvent");
        dispatched = super.dispatchTouchEvent(e);
        if (!dispatched && mDetector != null)
            dispatched = mDetector.onTouchEvent(e);
        return dispatched;
    }`. I've applied the solution in "Turbo Alarm" app if you would like to check it.